# Jackson JSON parser invalid utf-8 start byte

Tags: java, json, exception, jackson

I'm trying to parse the following JSON and I keep getting a `JsonParseException`:

```
{
   "episodes":{
      "description":"Episode 3 – Oprah's Surprise Patrol from 1\/20\/04\nTake a trip down memory lane and hear all your favorite episodes of The Oprah Winfrey Show from the last 25 seasons -- everyday on your radio!"
   }
}
```

also fails on this JSON

```
{
   "episodes":{
      "description":"After 20 years in sports talk…he’s still the top dog!  Catch Christopher “Mad Dog” Russo weekday afternoons on Mad Dog Radio as he tells it like it is…Give the Doggie a call at 888-623-3646."
   }
}
```

Exception:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x96
 at [Source: C:\Json Test Files\episodes.txt; line: 3, column: 33]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1291)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:385)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._reportInvalidInitial(Utf8StreamParser.java:2236)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._reportInvalidChar(Utf8StreamParser.java:2230)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._finishString2(Utf8StreamParser.java:1467)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._finishString(Utf8StreamParser.java:1394)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser.getText(Utf8StreamParser.java:113)
    at com.niveus.jackson.Main.parseEpisodes(Main.java:37)
    at com.niveus.jackson.Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

Code:

```
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        parseEpisodes("C:\\Json Test Files\\episodes.txt");
    }
    public static void parseEpisodes(String filename) {
        JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
        JsonParser parser = null;
        String nameField = null;
        
        try {
            parser = factory.createJsonParser(new File(filename));
            
            parser.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_CONTROL_CHARS, true);
            parser.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER, true);
            
            JsonToken token = parser.nextToken();
            nameField = parser.getText();
            String desc = null;
            
            while (token != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (nameField.equals("episodes")) {
                    while (token != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
                        if (nameField.equals("description")) {
                            parser.nextToken();
                            desc = parser.getText();
                        }
                        
                        token = parser.nextToken();
                        nameField = parser.getText();
                    }
                }
                
                token = parser.nextToken();
                nameField = parser.getText();
            }
            
            System.out.println(desc);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The character at column 33 is `–`, and the reason this would be the byte `0x96` is that the file is physically encoded as Windows-1252. You need to save the file in UTF-8, windows-1252 is not a valid encoding for json. How to do this depends on what text editor you are using.

See [JSON RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt):

> 1. Encoding
>
>    JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is
>      UTF-8.

Comment: I download a JSON string response as UTF-8 and write the contents to a .txt file (UTF-8) onto my Android SD storage and then copy that file to my desktop.

Comment: Also i'm using notepad on Windows to open the file.

Comment: Somewhere in the process, what you _believe_ is UTF-8 is actually Windows-1252.  My guess is the original download is mislabeled.  BTW, 0x96 is the character "en-dash", which is what MS Word uses for a hyphen.   In the second example, the culprit is the ellipsis character, also a MS Word idiosyncrasy.

Comment: @AndroidNoob the byte `0x96` will never appear alone in an utf-8 encoded file since it's a continuation byte. Open the file in notepad, press save as, and select `UTF-8` from the Encoding menu.

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced similar issue. open your json in Notepad ++, then in encoding drop down select as UTF-8. and save the text to other file. doing this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Everything mentioned here I tried and none solved my issue, so I manually typed the payload and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I would like to share something that works for me. It is possible to ignore the character in the following way.

1. Define a charset decoded

   StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder().onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
2. Use to read the InputStream

   InputStreamReader stream = new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream(), CHARSET_DECODER)
3. Use the Jackson CSV mapper to read the content

   new CsvMapper().readerFor(Map.class).readValues(stream);

The key element here is the charset decoder with the option IGNORE in the malformed input.