# Spring, Hibernate: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x80 error when trying to save images

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm trying to send a json containing array of images:

```
{
 Title: "Hello",
 images: [
   { 
     fileName: "hello",
     data: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAA..."
   }
  ]
}
```

and save it to this entity in Spring+Hibernate:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "flat")
public class Flat {

    private Title;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        mappedBy = "flat")
    private List<File> images = new ArrayList<>(); //see the File entity below

...
```

here is the File entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "file")
public class File {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "flat_id")
    private Flat flat;

    @Lob
    private byte[] data;
...
```

(both entities have an id field)

So, it all works when the "data" field in "images" is empty. Otherwise, I'm getting an error in spring:

```
JsonMappingException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x80
```

I saw a similiar question  here([Jackson JSON parser invalid utf-8 start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830346/jackson-json-parser-invalid-utf-8-start-byte)) and the answer there was about wrong encodings, but I still can't understand how can I solve it in my case.

Comment: How are you generating your Json? What library are you using? What annotations are you using to configure the json generation? Why do you think a `byte[]` would serialise as a url in the form `"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAA...` ?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I'm reading an image using FileReader, then geting a src like so: src = reader.result , and then putting it to "data" field. It doesn't even works with String instead of byte[] :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data:
```

is actually an URL format (see [IETF](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2397.txt)). So you *really* couldn't use that anyway.
Even if you had only

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAA...
```

that is an encoded Base64 `String`, not an array of byte.
You need to process the `data` field, and transform the `String` to `byte[]` again.

I'd suggest you to avoid directly mapping a request/response body to a JPA Entity, instead create a DTO class, which you'll use to map to the Entity (and viceversa), applying the required transformations.