# Removing specific namespaces from SOAP response gives encoding error - Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xa0

Tags: xslt, encoding, utf-8

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns4:getAllResponse xmlns:ns4=\"http://xxx.xxx.xxx\" xmlns:ns3=\"http://yyy.yyy.yyy\" xmlns:ns2=\"http://zzz.zzz.zzz\">
            <result>...
            </result>
         </ns4:getAllResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Above is my soap response. From the response "xmlns:ns3="http://yyy.yyy.yyy" and "xmlns:ns2="http://zzz.zzz.zzz" need to be removed.

My .xsl file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:typ="http://xxx.yyyy.zzzz/types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- remove all extra namespaces from child nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="result|*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Add soap namespace as by default it gets dropped -->
    <xsl:template xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" match="Envelope" >
        <xsl:element name="soap:Envelope" >
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Add soap namespace as by default it gets dropped -->
    <xsl:template match="Body" >
        <xsl:element name="soap:Body">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--empty template suppresses the attribute xsi:type -->
    <xsl:template match="@*[name() = 'xsi:type']"/>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With the above xsl tranformation some of the endpoints give the response as per expectation but few endpoints gives below error.

```
    Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xa0 (at char #84017, byte #83999)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.dom.XSLTCDTMManager.getDTM(XSLTCDTMManager.java:426)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.dom.XSLTCDTMManager.getDTM(XSLTCDTMManager.java:214)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getDOM(TransformerImpl.java:548)
    ... 54 more

Dec 08, 2021 3:30:19 PM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
method has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Error writing to XMLStreamWriter.
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor$SoapOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapOutInterceptor.java:317)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor$SoapOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapOutInterceptor.java:293)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:112)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.wrapExceptionAsFault(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:366)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:324)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor.handleMessage(OutgoingChainInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:299)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:218)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:274)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.wdpr.ee.loggingapi.filter.HttpLoggingFilter.doFilter(HttpLoggingFilter.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.wdpr.ee.authz.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:196)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:364)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:624)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:831)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1650)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: No open start element, when trying to write end element
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.throwOutputError(BaseStreamWriter.java:1537)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.reportNwfStructure(BaseStreamWriter.java:1566)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseNsStreamWriter.doWriteEndTag(BaseNsStreamWriter.java:648)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseNsStreamWriter.writeEndElement(BaseNsStreamWriter.java:280)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor$SoapOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapOutInterceptor.java:303)
    ... 48 more
```

Could anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need is:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will remove *all* redundant namespace declarations and keep only the required ones - `xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"` and `xmlns:ns4="http://xxx.xxx.xxx"` in your example.

Comment: Thanks for response. But for the endpoints for which I was getting error still has the same behavior. Could you help on that please. You can find the error stack trace from the post

Comment: I am afraid I have no idea what an "endpoint" is. AFAICT the error is not related to the XSLT code itself. Perhaps you have some stray character in your XSLT document, or the encoding is wrong.

Comment: There is no possibility to have any stray character in XSLT file. So there should be something with encoding. But I tried removing UTF-8 encoding also from XSLT file. But no use. If I remove this XSLT part I am getting response with extra namespace without any issue. And is there any other way to remove namespace apart from XSLT.

Comment: Can we do something to remove namespace from WSDL file itself?

Comment: I suggest you try and copy the above code into a new file and save it with UTF-8 encoding (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830346/jackson-json-parser-invalid-utf-8-start-byte). In any case, this problem is not related to XSLT and I cannot help you with it. And I would recommend against trying to process XML in any way other than XSLT.